# Clone closest span for each of ul appendTo next class

Tags: jquery

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/koqili/1/edit

## QUESTION:

I want to clone the `li.has-children a span` immediately above (closest?) the `ul.waSlideMenu-menu` and then inside that `ul.waSlideMenu-menu` the first child has a class `li.waSlideMenu-back`, that is where I want the clone. Right now all I can figure out is cloning every single one of them and putting them inside the area. I am crappy at this.

**WRONG:**

[image]

I have this script here:

```
$('.waSlideMenu-menu').closest('.has-children').find('span').clone().appendTo($('.waSlideMenu-back').children());
```

And what it's doing is cloning all of the spans and putting them all inside the `.waSlideMenu-back`. Here's the generated html of this mess:

**WRONG:**

```
<ul class="waSlideMenu-menu waSlideMenu-inheritedmenu">
   <li class="waSlideMenu-back"><a href="#">Up / <span>About Us</span><span>About Us Child</span><span>Oahu<span></span></span><span></span><span>Australia</span><span>California</span><span>Indian Ocean</span><span>Indonesia</span><span>Atlantic Ocean</span><span>Europe</span><span>South Africa</span><span>Canary Islands</span></a></li>
```

**What I want it to be is**:

```
<ul class="waSlideMenu-menu waSlideMenu-inheritedmenu">
    <li class="waSlideMenu-back">
    <a href="#">
        Up / <span>The text of the Span inside the previous .has-children</span>
    </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: a bit confusing. in DEMO there is no class with `ul`, also there is invalid markup in your `Wrong` section of question. two adjacent span is closing. Please recheck the question

Comment: ul.waSlideMenu-menu, not a class with ul. The wrong section is wrong, that's part of the wrongness. Thanks

Comment: I did, but since it's before the element, it's like a parent but a child of the parent before. Check out the bin in the question, click on some things, you'll see what I'm trying to do

Comment: you have `waSlideMenu-menu` in parent and child ul. will you make a clean ul li menu on jsfiddle.

Comment: you need `Up/ About US` types.. right?

Comment: Yes, I fell asleep after you emailed me about 8 hours ago. Thank you so very, very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your HTML is not semantically correct , I have added the parent category name on first children of `li`. is that you are looking for?

I tried more cleaner approach (differ from the DEMO)  which is less dependent to class selector. it would be faster

```
var menu = $('#nav ul');
$('a', menu).on('click', function(){
  var clickedText = $(this).find('span').text();
  var parentDirAnchor = $(this).next('ul').children().first().find('a');
  /*
   one can use either of below approach, dont know which is faster ?
   $(this).next('ul').children(':first-child').find('a');
   $(this).siblings('ul').children('li:first').children('a');
  */
  parentDirAnchor.html(' Up / <b>' + clickedText + '</b>');
```

});

### [`Working DEMO`](http://jsbin.com/lunecukapofi/1/edit)